# Room database inefficiency

Tags: android, performance

just got started with android room database an I like the efficiency it brings to the android team and the general programming experince. But currently facing some efficiency issues .
my issue is that for a class marked with @database annotation we are recqured to pass all the enties inside the annotation as google explains  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

so what if I have like over 50 entity classes and I want to easen the process of passing the classes my Database class is there any option for me ?? 
 I happen to come from a spring background and I like the similarity between the two though in spring there is no such a condition but everything works smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so what if I have like over 50 entity classes and I want to easen the process of passing the classes my Database class is there any option for me ?

Room cannot make assumptions about which `RoomDatabase` the visible `@Entity` classes belong to. For example, `WorkManager` might use Room, and if it does, the `WorkManager` entities belong to its database, not yours.

You could write some sort of code generator that uses your own personal rules to generate that list of classes, if you wanted.

Comment: this sounds quite understandable but I think it would be better if android itself builds a mechanism such that say they define annotations to use in the entity classes which will tell Room the  RoomDatabase that the given Entity belongs to.